# What does selecting "Normal map" in the image sampling panel actually do?

Tags: interface

Whenever I import an image in Blender to be used as a normal map I have to select "Normal map" in "Image Sampling" under "Texture". I remember that this was not always the case, at least I don't remember having to do that in older versions (aroung 8 years ago) though I could be misremembering. I'm also asking because as a programmer I've used normal maps in OpenGL and they went through the usual texture pipeline, no special treatment needed. So I wonder what Blender is doing with this information.

Comment: The normal map option exists in 2.49. I think it is similar to the [non-colour data](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/nodes/types/textures/image.html#properties) option in cycles nodes, in that it prevents any colour space transforms altering the image. When enabled the map space can also be selected so that the image can be interpreted differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using the old Blender Render engine, this checkbox just tells Blender that the texture in question is a normal map rather than a bump map so that it knows which shader to use.